# React Native instantiate singleton native module in Swift

Tags: swift, react-native

I have a `CloudStorage` native module that will be available on `NativeModules.CloudStorage`. I know the module is instantiated as a singleton by React Native. Is there a way to access the same singleton from my application delegate, like this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
 ...
 [[CloudStorage sharedInstance] handleNotification]
}
```

From my understanding, at the time when we call `sharedInstance`, React Native have already created a singleton instance somewhere by calling `[CloudStorage new]`, which will be different from the `[CloudStorage sharedInstance]` What's the best way to create a singleton native module that you can also access via the objective-c/swift side?

Comment: Are you sure react native instantiates classes of native modules only once? I need to verify this because the singleton pattern in Swift doesn't allow returning an old instance on consequent instantiations.

Comment: @Noitidart pretty sure it does, but you are probably better off diving into react native code or ask core devs.

Comment: Thanks randomor I'll let you know if I find anything out.

Comment: so did you guys find how this can be achieved ?